# How to convert json data to records and insert into a using in sql server

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am new to sqlserver. I want to convert json data into records and insert into a table.
I have json data like

```
    {  
   "HEADER":[  
      {  
         "seq_id":343,
         "max_processed_scn":649044274,
         "time_processed":"13-MAR-19 09.03.23.081055 PM",
         "status":"COMPLETED"
      },
      {  
         "seq_id":344,
         "max_processed_scn":649214903,
         "time_processed":"15-MAR-19 12.49.31.606172 PM",
         "status":"COMPLETED"
      }
   ],
   "DETAIL":[  
      {  
         "seq_id":11215,
         "event_id":1,
         "caller_seq":343,
         "event_description":"BEGIN.."
      },
      {  
         "seq_id":11216,
         "event_id":2,
         "caller_seq":343,
         "event_description":"STARTING"
      },
      {  
         "seq_id":11217,
         "event_id":2,
         "caller_seq":343,
         "event_description":"STARTED "
      } "event_description":"TOTAL"

   ]
   }
```

so the array "header" I want to insert into one table and the other array "Detail" into another.Can anyone help me on achieving this. Thanks in advance

so I need detail table data like

```
seq_id  max_processed_scn        time_processed               status
343      649044274          13-MAR-19 09.03.23.081055 PM    COMPLETED
344      649214903          15-MAR-19 12.49.31.606172 PM    COMPLETED
```

I used this query :

```
   DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json =  
N'[{  
   "HEADER":[  
      {  
         "seq_id":343,
         "max_processed_scn":649044274,
         "time_processed":"13-MAR-19 09.03.23.081055 PM",
         "status":"COMPLETED"
      },
      {  
         "seq_id":344,
         "max_processed_scn":649214903,
         "time_processed":"15-MAR-19 12.49.31.606172 PM",
         "status":"COMPLETED"
      }
   ],
   "DETAIL":[  
      {  
         "seq_id":11215,
         "event_id":1,
         "caller_seq":343,
         "event_description":"BEGIN.."
      },
      {  
         "seq_id":11216,
         "event_id":2,
         "caller_seq":343,
         "event_description":"STARTING"
      },
      {  
         "seq_id":11217,
         "event_id":2,
         "caller_seq":343,
         "event_description":"STARTED "
      } "event_description":"TOTAL"

   ]
   }
 ]'
SELECT *  
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.HEADER')  
  WITH (seq_id INT, max_processed_scn INT, time_processed NVARCHAR(100), [status] NVARCHAR(100))
```

Comment: I *assume* you're using SQL Server 2016/2017? Showing what you want your data to look like in SQL Server will help. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: If you have SQL Server 2016+, this is trivially achieved with `OPENJSON` (e.g. `SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.HEADER') WITH (seq_id INT, max_processed_scn INT, time_processed NVARCHAR(100), [status] NVARCHAR(100))` and another one for `DETAIL`). If you don't, it's almost not worth doing in T-SQL; client code is much better equipped.

Comment: Show your attempt in your post @pythonCoder. That code is unreadable there. I've added the SQL Server 2017 tag for you, as that's really important here.

Comment: @pythonCoder add what you tried and what the problem is in your question, not the comments

Comment: @pythonCoder btw the JSON string you posted has no `HEADERS` attribute. It's an object that contains  `HEADER` and `DETAIL` properties. Those contain arrays. At the very least you need to fix the names and access the array elements

Comment: @pythonCoder Jeroen's query works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below queries in sql server 2016 onwards to read the Json data and insert in required tables

**Sample Data**

```
declare @json varchar(max) =' {  
   "HEADER":[  
      {  
         "seq_id":343,
         "max_processed_scn":649044274,
         "time_processed":"13-MAR-19 09.03.23.081055 PM",
         "status":"COMPLETED"
      },
      {  
         "seq_id":344,
         "max_processed_scn":649214903,
         "time_processed":"15-MAR-19 12.49.31.606172 PM",
         "status":"COMPLETED"
      }
   ],
   "DETAIL":[  
      {  
         "seq_id":11215,
         "event_id":1,
         "caller_seq":343,
         "event_description":"BEGIN.."
      },
      {  
         "seq_id":11216,
         "event_id":2,
         "caller_seq":343,
         "event_description":"STARTING"
      },
      {  
         "seq_id":11217,
         "event_id":2,
         "caller_seq":343,
         "event_description":"STARTED "
      } 

   ]
   }
   '
```

**Query to select Header data**

```
  SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.HEADER') WITH (seq_id INT, max_processed_scn INT, time_processed NVARCHAR(50), [status] NVARCHAR(50))
```

**Query to select Detail data**

```
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.DETAIL') WITH (seq_id INT, event_id INT, caller_seq int, event_description NVARCHAR(255))
```